# How do you generate a live Swagger API page for your hosted Swagger API?

Tags: node.js, heroku, swagger, swagger-ui

I have created an API using [Swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger).

My customers will be able to make calls to my service like

```
https://theservice.com/data/items/category1/12345
```

This is fine and works ok.

However, I would like to have a page where they can see all available API calls, similar to how Swagger generates it on their [SwaggerEditor app](http://editor.swagger.io/#/). For example by visiting `https://theservice.com/index.html` I would like them to see the API docs.

Is it possible (within Swagger) to do this on a live system (not just locally with `swagger project edit` which I already know)?
If yes, how?

Comment: Looks like you might have a typo:  "customers will not be able to make calls to my service like..."  I think you meant "customers will NOW be able to make calls..."  You might want to correct this to clarify the question for other users.

Comment: @TedEpstein good catch, fixed it. sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) to describe your API, then generating some scaffolding code using the built-in generator. From your tags, I assume this is node.js code.  You'll need to add your own logic to the generated code to complete this API implementation (if you haven't already done so).

If this is correct, then the interactive Swagger-UI documentation you're looking for should be available in your generated API at `/docs` endpoint, relative to the base URL of your running service.

The generated node.js project includes the Swagger spec you created in the editor, and uses [Swagger-Tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools) to do the runtime magic. Among other things, Swagger-Tools auto-wires your Swagger spec to the `/docs` endpoint, and manages routing of requests to the generated controllers, based on information provided in your Swagger spec.

Note that the `/docs` page will look and behave somewhat differently from the documentation widget you see in the Swagger editor. The one in your application uses [Swagger-UI](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/), which is the runtime component for documentation, with interactive sandbox testing. [Swagger-Editor](http://swagger.io/swagger-editor/) has its own built-in documentation UI, and this is not currently packaged for use outside of the Swagger-Editor.

If you've already implemented an API, independent of the Swagger editor and code generator, you can still generate node.js code to see how to incorporate Swagger-Tools into your existing API implementation. Or, as [wing328](https://stackoverflow.com/users/677735/wing328) suggests, take a look at [Swagger-UI](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/) to see how you can add your own documentation page.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [swagger-ui](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/) and here is an example: http://petstore.swagger.io/

As you can see, it not only lists out all the available API endpoints but also lets visitors (developers) to try it out directly in the web page.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks